# Approve contract to withdraw funds from users's wallet

Tags: solidity, erc-20, metamask, wallets, wallet-transfer

I want to achieve the following flow:

- A user clicks a button allowing my contract to spend funds on the user's behalf
- A user clicks a second button whereupon funds are transferred from the user's wallet to the contract.

From my understanding this needs to be split up into two transactions.

So i thought something like this would work:

Contract code:

```js
function approve(uint amount) public {
  // Calling this function first from remix
  ERC20(Token_address).approve(address(this), amount)
}

function transferFrom(uint amount) public {
  // Then calling this function from remix
  ERC20(Token_address).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount)
}
```

But it gives me gas estimation failiure inside of remix. I suspect this is because i cannot have the contract call the `approve()` function. It needs to be called from the user whom is approving the contract to withdraw its funds. How can i achieve this if the user isn't a another smart contract but just a person with a metamask wallet?

Comment: The user should call `approve`, not the contract.

Comment: ok but if you think about full stack(frontend - metamask and backend) user has to make two metamask transaction. 1) approve method( with metamask) => due to gas consumption
then
2) sending balance(with metamas) => also required gas namely this isnt done by just by one metamask click is it true?

Comment: Approve was designed to be called from FrontEnd, not from another contract?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right, your contract should not call the `approve` method itself, as it would become the `msg.sender` in the context of the token smart contract, which would cause your contract to self-approve.

You want the user to approve your contract and you can write a script to achieve this. An exemple with web3js 1.2 could be :

```
var erc20Instance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,Token_address);

erc20Instance.methods.approve(contractAddress, amount).send({from: userAddress}, 
function(err, transactionHash) {
//some code
});
```

with :

- abi : the abi of the token contract. You can use https://ethereumdev.io/abi-for-erc20-contract-on-ethereum/ for an ERC20.
- contractAddress : the contract address to approve.
- amount : the amount to approve. Note that you can "disapprove" the contract by sending a new transaction with an amount of 0, as it will override the previous value.
- userAddress : the sender's address.

Answer (score 2):

The `approve` function is used to set allowance for the current sender. If you would call it from your own contract, you would approve spending the tokens *for* your own contract.

Instead of calling `approve` through a smart contract, you have to send the transaction directly from the user to the ERC-20 contract, with the address of your own smart contract specified as `_sender`. To do this, just send a transaction using MetaMask's API.