# Transfer eth to accounts in Remix javasctipt VM solidity V 0.6.0+

Tags: remix, payable, transfer

I am simple man, but learning Eth Dev.

I am testing a contract in Remix however I can't transfer Eth between the accounts in the javascript VM (using solidity V0.6.0 +). I have researched for a while but most implementations are in version 0.4. and i don't see the point in developing my smart contract on old versions especially considering secutiry and the great contracts made by Open Zeppelin.

So breaking my issue down to basic questions...

**How do I transfer ethereum between accounts in REMIX JavaScript VM using solidity V0.6.0+?**

All i want to do is send 1 ether from the user to the contract owner from (ownable.sol).From there I can build the logic i want for the actual contract.

```
 function Fund() public payable{
        address(owner).transfer(1 ether);
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer Ether from the contract by making the to address payable and the unit of transfer will be wei by default,

```
    function Fund(address payable _toAddress, uint256 _amountInWei) 
    external payable {
        address myAddress = address(this);
        if (myAddress.balance >= _amountInWei) {
            _toAddress.transfer(_amountInWei);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Huge thanks for the reply @Noushad. I can get it to compile but the wei transfer doesn't work I enter a value (and address to send it too) but the wei value remains 0.

This is what I get in the console.

'
from  0x1e8a23b4009
 to  coinA.Fund(address,uint256) 0x05aaf52e09e3
 gas  3000000 gas 
 transaction cost  23960 gas 
 execution cost  1024 gas 
 input  0xda8...02710
 decoded input  {
 "address _toAddress": "0x1228d1906b46b971b71fA363bd5a4c7FCc520e09",
 "uint256 _amountInWei": {
  "_hex": "0x2710"
 }
}
 decoded output  {}
 logs  []
 value  0 wei <<< still @ zero :(
'

Comment: does your contract have ether balance to send ? Can you check it by this function, function balanceInContract() public  view returns(uint256) {
        
        address myAddress = address(this);
        return myAddress.balance;
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the contract transfer ether on behalf of address **A** to another address **B** unless **A** approves the contract to do so! I asked a [similar question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80266/approve-contract-to-withdraw-funds-from-userss-wallet) in the past which might be helpful to you!