# How to approve an transfer with safeERC from OpenZepplelin

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

My contract does like this;

```
pragma solidity 0.6.2;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/EnumerableSet.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "./IDTToken.sol";

contract Stacking is Ownable{

    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    IDTToken stk = new IDTToken();
    mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => uint256)) public stackers;
    mapping(address => uint256) public poolBalance; 

    event Deposit(address indexed user, uint256 indexed pid, uint256 amount);
    event Withdraw(address indexed user, uint256 indexed pid, uint256 amount);

    struct PoolInfo {
        IERC20 tokenStack;           
        uint256 allocPoint;       
        uint256 lastRewardBlock; 
        uint256 accIDTPerShare; 
        }

    function deposit(uint256 _amount, uint256 _id) public payable {
        PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[_id];
        updatePool(_id);
        stackers[_id][msg.sender] = stackers[_id][msg.sender].add(_amount); 
        pool.tokenStack.safeTransferFrom(address(msg.sender), address(this), _amount);
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, _id, _amount);
         }

    function getERCapprove(IERC20 _token, address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool){
        
        return _token.approve(_spender, _value);
        }
}
```

In the front end;

```
export const stackToken = async (stacking, token, account, amount, id, web3) => {
amount = web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'ether')
await stacking.methods.getERCapprove(token, stacking.options.address, amount).send({ from: account 
}).on('transactionHash',(hash) => {
  console.log(hash)
  stacking.methods.deposit(amount,id).send({from : account})
  })  
}
```

So when I approve the token it seams to be working. I receive a transaction hash from that call.

But the call for the transfer is causing an error.

If I make the deposit with a token that is not using safeERC, just a plain erc20 standard.
I get the following error;

```
VM Exception while processing transaction: revert SafeERC20: low-level call failed
```

If I make the call to a token that uses safeERC
I get the following error;

```
VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance
```

So I'm not sure if it's the approval or the transfer that isn't working

Comment: Is it possible that the approve function cannot be called from and by the contract to the token contract? If I make the call straight from to token contract it is working. Not with the external getERCapprove function. Which would make sense since otherwise I could get an address approved from a contract call instead of the real owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see this function  :

```
   function getERCapprove(IERC20 _token, address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool){
    
    return _token.approve(_spender, _value);
    }
```

Here the `Stacking` contract approves `_spender` for `_token`. What you are looking for is the opposite : the user approves the `Stacking` contract to let it transfer his tokens in the `deposit` method.

In order to do this, the user has to interact directly with the token contract (`pool.tokenStack`) and call `approve` (the call must not come from the `Stacking` contract). Then you should be able to execute this line in the `deposit` function :

```
        pool.tokenStack.safeTransferFrom(address(msg.sender), address(this), _amount);
```

Also take a look at this, which is similar to your issue : [Approve contract to withdraw funds from users's wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80266/approve-contract-to-withdraw-funds-from-userss-wallet/80269#80269).